# Get byte array with Android Vision scanning pdf417 barcode

Tags: android, android-vision

I used the [android vision sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader) for scanning PDF417 barcode on the South African driver license.
For decoding the information I need to pass the byte array to another library.
But I can get only get a `barcode.rawValue` that is a `String`.

I am trying to obtain `bytes[]` from the string using `barcode.rawValue.getBytes()` but this returns an array which is not working with the decoding library.

I need an analogue of `Pdf417MobiScanData.getBarcodeRawData().getAllData()`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Found solution:

```
byte[] rawLicenseCard = barcode.rawValue.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```